# ASP.NET locale specific resource file not being picked up

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization

Everything works ok for the default invariant resource file (`resources.resx`) - my label's text is being picked up using

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resource, key);
```

When I set

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hk");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hk");
```

The locale specific resource file (`resources.zh-hk.resx`) is being ignored and the default invariant one above is being used.

I've tried renaming the files to test they are in the right location..and that's fine.

What's missing from the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be where I was registering the locale, this needs to be in the PreRequestHandler not the BeginRequest one.

```
application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += SetLocale;
```

not

```
application.BeginRequest += SetLocale;

private void SetLocale(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LocalizationHelper.SetThreadCurrentCulture();
}
```

Obvious!

Answer (score 0):

you should be setting it like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-hk");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-hk");
```

check this one out: [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Comment: btw this has no effect. see my answer which works either way up.